# StructureMap Purge Cached Instances

Tags: structuremap

I'm having trouble resetting StructureMap's configuration.  This only fails when I run *all* my tests en mass.  A previous test is Injecting an instance of SingleInvoicePresenter, but by the time I get to this test, I need all caching gone.  I would think that ResetDefaults() would clear any previously injected objects out, but this test fails on the assert (when run with all the other tests)

```
    StructureMap.ObjectFactory.ResetDefaults();
    StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Configure(x => { x.For<SingleInvoicePresenter>().AlwaysUnique(); });

    SingleInvoicePresenter P1 = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<SingleInvoicePresenter>();
    SingleInvoicePresenter P2 = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<SingleInvoicePresenter>();

    Assert.AreNotSame(P1, P2);
```

Edit - I would think this would work even without the line

```
StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Configure(x => { x.For<SingleInvoicePresenter>().AlwaysUnique(); });
```

but it fails with or without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StructureMap.ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf<SingleInvoicePresenter>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the global objectfactory of structuremap should be avoided in your unit tests.  Rather in your test setup you would want to create a new container and pass that or an Icontainer reference into your system under test.